# getting the following error = ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_message':messages, 'message_date':dates })

# convert message_date type
    
df['message_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['message_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M - ')

df.rename(columns={'message_date': 'date'}, inplace=True)

df.head()
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2028\475687816.py in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame({'user_message':messages, 'message_date':dates })
      2 
      3 # convert message_date type
      4 
      5 df['message_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['message_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M - ')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    634         elif isinstance(data, dict):
    635             # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 636             mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    637         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    638             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    500         # TODO: can we get rid of the dt64tz special case above?
    501 
--> 502     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
    503 
    504 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    118         # figure out the index, if necessary
    119         if index is None:
--> 120             index = _extract_index(arrays)
    121         else:
    122             index = ensure_index(index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _extract_index(data)
    672             lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    673             if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 674                 raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
    675 
    676             if have_dicts:

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

Trying to create a pandas dataframe where 2 columns will be created by the names user_message and message_date.

Also in the next line i've tried to convert message_date(column) into date time in the defined format.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your lists `messages` and `dates` in this line `df = pd.DataFrame({'user_message':messages, 'message_date':dates })` are not the same length, you may want to verify that they are the same length.